# How to do multiple matches on Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

I have two different lists but I need to match certain values (not similar). For example, suppose I have the following table, I need to know if I have "DD" in List A and JJ in List B on the same row. How can I do that? I tried to apply the function "AND" on the entire columns but that didn't work.

[image: Table]

Update based on squillman's advise:

The real problem is that I have the following table for attendance reports from different instructors through a Google Form. I need to check if each instructor is submitting his report every week or not automatically. So, I need the second table to be filled out automatically. I tried to check using "AND" but that didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect the real problem is more complicated than this example.  Are you trying to dynamically compare values from somehere to those in List A and List B, and not just a hardcoded "DD" and "JJ"?  If so, please update your question to include what you're really trying to compare.

Comment: Thanks, squilman. I have updated the question based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `COUNTIFS`. Use the following formula and populate your table with it:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$F2,$B:$B,G$1)>0,"Done","")
```

Example:
[image]

You'll need to adjust the ranges to match your worksheets. Pay attention to the absolute and relative addresses

Comment: This resolved the issue! Thank you very much =)